# How do you teach kids appreciation and respect for other cultures?

Tags: behavior

Recently, I was walking with a friend from an ESL group I'm in. He speaks Spanish as a first language and I speak English first. We're in a group with other Spanish and English speakers so we can try and learn the other's language. A young friend of mine (let's call her Sarah) started walking next to us, and I introduced the two to each other. After I had introduced them, she told him, loudly, with exaggerated hand motions, "I... *Sarah*!"

I know she was trying to communicate with him, but that wasn't the proper way to do it. I don't have kids, but if I did and they did that, I wouldn't know how to correct the behavior or explain why it was wrong. How can you teach kids respect for others from other cultures?

Comment: Adding "if I had kids, how would I handle it..." [doesn't really make a situation between intelligent adults appropriate for a parenting site](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In that case, a lot would depend on the age of the child and their behavior. We prefer questions to be about a problem you actually are facing; the title is an appropriate question for parenting, but the body of the question is not only unlikely but also isn't really a parenting problem.

Comment: The way to teach our own children is to model how to behave and correct them if they are wrong. The way to stop someone who is a teen or older and not your relation is different. That depends on the person being spoken to and **if** they require you to come to their defence. Later you could tell Sarah, that speaking louder and talking down to someone else is not the way to help, but in the same way you'd wish to be corrected for your own social gaffes.

Comment: It's great to think ahead about how you would want to raise your children to not be culturally insensitive in such situations but in this particular case, I would have told Sarah, "Oh, that's not necessary. He understands English well enough" and call her out on her insensitivity right then and there. As an adult, or I assume close to, she should acknowledge her mistake and be able to learn and grow from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the general question just expose children to other cultures.  Children generally take everything as acceptable/normal/uneventful at a young age, they don't see anything different from an Stright American English speaking mom and someone speaking Spanish or a gay/trans/bi man or someone from some foreign land practicing some different religion when a child is so young they are still working on understanding the world enough to have an idea what 'normal' is.  So exposing a child from a young age to different cultures goes a very long way to making them respect other cultures.  Teaching them to respect anyone, be they from a different culture or the same one, is also important.  Modeling proper behavior by respecting other cultures yourself and expressing curiosity/excitement about learning about someone new/different helps.  But really just exposing them to different things does 90% of the work if combined with basic good parenting skills.